# cast string to int java android

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

How can I convert a String to an int in Java?

My String contains only numbers and I want to return the number it represents.

For example, given the string "1234" the result should be the number 1234

```
 String Availability = json.getString("Availability");before parsing value ="4" 
 int x = Integer.parseInt(Availability);here after parsing it gives me 2 i don't know why
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you posted? `json.getInt` is probably better (but probably does the same thing internally).

Comment: if i have number 4 Availability after parsing give me number 1

Comment: did you try to debug the value of `Availability` (please follow the naming convention, it should be `availability`.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` is very strict.  If it returns 1, it means your string is "1".

Comment: Sorry , `Integer.parseInt()` returns 2 if the  `Availability` = "4"

Comment: Provide a [mcve] without the JSON part (if `String availability` really contains "4" of couse). Since this parse should work, I suspect the problem come from your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the foll function Integer.valueOf here is an example

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int num = Integer.valueOf("22");
    num+=2;
    System.out.println(num); // output 24
}
```